# I'm getting every Time Random repeating Data in Sqlite Android I want Random data without repeating

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm getting many time repeating data from Sqlite / Android database. I want to get recode without repeating in Android cursor.

Here's my query:

```
public Cursor getQuizQuiestion(String cat, String level, String questionNo) {
    String QUERY_SELECT_QUIESTION = "SELECT * FROM " +TABLE_QUIESTION +" WHERE "+COL_CAT+  " = '" +cat+"' AND "
            +COL_LEVEL+ " = " +level+" ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(QUERY_SELECT_QUIESTION, null);

    return cursor;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I Have Simple Example if I Used In My Project I think MayBe IT's Help You;**

```
 public ArrayList<ModelRandomList>  getRandomData(String city){

    ArrayList<ModelRandomList> modelRandomListArrayListLists = new ArrayList<ModelRandomList>();


    String queryRandomData ="SELECT  DISTINCT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+COL_CITY + "=?"+ "Order BY RANDOM()";

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryRandomData,new String[] { String.valueOf(city) });

    if(cursor.getCount() != 0){

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            /*mName =cursor.getString(0);
            mCity = cursor.getString(1);

            Log.d(TAG,mName +" City "+mCity );*/


            ModelRandomList modelRandomList = new ModelRandomList();
            modelRandomList.setUserName(cursor.getString(0));
            modelRandomList.setUserCity(cursor.getString(1));

             modelRandomListArrayListLists.add(modelRandomList);
        }

        Random random = new Random();

        Collections.shuffle(modelRandomListArrayListLists,random);
    }


    Log.d(TAG, "Get Random Totla No of Recode Found "+cursor.getCount());



    return modelRandomListArrayListLists;
}
```

and in Your Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private SqlLiteDataBaseHelper sqlLiteDataBaseHelper;
private Button btGetRandomData;
private ArrayList<ModelRandomList> modelRandomLists;
private Button btSingleRandomData;
private int position = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    modelRandomLists = new ArrayList<ModelRandomList>();

    sqlLiteDataBaseHelper = new SqlLiteDataBaseHelper(MainActivity.this);

    try{

        if(sqlLiteDataBaseHelper.checkDataBase()){

            Log.e(TAG, "Data Base Already Exists");

        }else {

            sqlLiteDataBaseHelper.CopyDataBaseFromAsset();
        }

        sqlLiteDataBaseHelper.openDataBase();

        try {
            Log.e(TAG, "No Of Racode In DataBase " + sqlLiteDataBaseHelper.getDataCount());
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    init();
}

private void init() {

    btGetRandomData = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btRandomData);
    btSingleRandomData = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btSingleRandomData);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    btGetRandomData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            modelRandomLists = sqlLiteDataBaseHelper.getRandomData("A");

           for (ModelRandomList crt : modelRandomLists) {

                Log.e(TAG, " " + crt.getUserName());
                Log.e(TAG, " " + crt.getUserCity());

            }
        }
    });


    btSingleRandomData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            try{
                Log.d(TAG,modelRandomLists.get(position).getUserName());
                position ++;

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                position =0;
            }


        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to create unique results if you are querying over and over again.

Since you are not using the questionNo parameter and return a cursor anyway: why not just remove the limit 1 and add the [distinct](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_distinct_keyword.htm) clause to your statement?

If you do it that way, you can use your cursor to iterate over the unique questions:

```
String QUERY_SELECT_QUIESTION = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " +TABLE_QUIESTION +" WHERE "+COL_CAT+  " = '" +cat+"' AND "
        +COL_LEVEL+ " = " +level+" ORDER BY RANDOM()";
```

Then you can iterate over the questions until you have none or whatever your conditions are:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(QUERY_SELECT_QUIESTION, null);
try {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        //display question or copy them to a member or whatever
    }
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: Sorry Bro but can't understna i have no good knowledge android can u guide me how to get random data from data base without repeting in coursor

Comment: I have updated the answer. The key to get unique data is to query the data only once and use distinct

Answer (score 0):

You would have to keep a track of what questions have been seen before. What about this:

```
private List<Integer> seenQuestions = new ArrayList<>();

public Cursor getUseenQuizQuestion(String cat,String level,String questionNo) {

   Cursor cursor = getQuizQuiestion(cat, level, questionNo);
   while(cursor == null) { // This could be an infinite loop!!
       cursor = getQuizQuiestion(cat, level, questionNo); 
   } 
   return cursor;
}

private Cursor getQuizQuiestion(String cat,String level,String questionNo){
    String QUERY_SELECT_QUIESTION = "SELECT * FROM " +TABLE_QUIESTION +" WHERE "+COL_CAT+  " = '" +cat+"' AND "
            +COL_LEVEL+ " = " +level+" ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(QUERY_SELECT_QUIESTION, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
       int resultId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
        if(seenQuestions.contains(resultId)) {
             cursor.close();
             return null;
        }

       seenQuestions.add(resultId);
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

^ the code sample above has many flaws and could loop infinitely.

But the point is you need to keep track of what has been returned and query again if you have seen it.

Alternatively, you could allow your DB query to return all data and then use a Random value to select one of the items.